# Mongoose - Find object with any key and specific subkey

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a Mongo database that contains objects such as :

```json
[
  {
    "test": {
      "123123": {
        "someField": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "test": {
      "323143": {
        "someField": "lalala"
      },
      "121434": {
        "someField": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "test": {
      "4238023": {
        "someField": "afafa"
      }
    }
  },
]
```

As you can see, the keys right under "test" can vary.

I want to find all documents that have at least one `someField` that is not null.

Something like find : `"test.*.someField": { $ne: null }` ( * represents any value here)

How can i do this in mongoose ? I'm thinking an aggregation pipeline will be needed here but not exactly sure how.

Constraints :

- I don't have much control over the db schema in this scenario.
- Ideally i don't want to have to do this logic in nodeJS, I would like to query directly via the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trickiest part here is that you cannot search keys that match a pattern. Luckily there is a workaround. Yes, you do need an aggregation pipeline.

Let's look at an individual document:

```
  {
    "test": {
      "4238023": {
        "someField": "afafa"
      }
    }
  }
```

We need to query `someField`, but to get to it, we need to somehow circumvent `4238023` because it varies with each document. What if we could break that `test` object down and look at it presented like so:

```
      {
        "k": "4238023",
        "v": {
          "someField": "afafa"
        }
      }
```

Suddenly, it get a heck of a lot easier to query it. Well, mongodb aggreation offers a function called `$objectToArray` which does exactly that.

So what we are going to do is:

1. Convert the `test` object into an array for each document.
2. Match only documents where AT LEAST ONE `v.someField` is not null.
3. Put it back together to look as your original documents, minus the ones that do not match the null criterion.

So, here is the pipeline you need:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "arr": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT.test"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      arr: {
        $elemMatch: {
          "v.someField": {
            $ne: null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "test": {
        $arrayToObject: "$arr"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/b_VNuOLgUb2

Note that in mongoose you will run this aggregation the same way you would do it in a terminal... well plus the `.then`.

```
YourCollection.aggregate([
   ...
   ...
])
.then(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: Wow ! What a good quality answer :) Thanks a lot @codemonkey . That resolves exactly how i wanted.

Comment: @Rose Glad it helped.